# How to dump the content of an item in a TODO list on a file

Tags: org-mode

Suppose that one has a list of items on a file `koko.org` (hereafter called the `org file`), as follows:

```
* heading A

 FOO

* heading B

  BAR
```

The list contains two items. My objective is to have a macro, preferably within the scope of an item, that will trigger the following actions:

1. obtain the heading of the current item,
2. capture the contents of the item on a given buffer, and
3. save the content of the buffer in a file.

e.g. the first item after the macro is called will save a file `text.txt` in a directory called `A` containing the text `FOO`, and similarly for the second item.